# Can I deauthorize some but not all computers for iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I'm trying to burn a CD in iTunes on a new computer, but can't because the computer isn't authorized yet.

When I try to authorize it (`Store -> Authorize This Computer...`), a window pops up stating:

> You cannot authorize more than 5 computers.
>   You have already authorized 5 computers with this account. 
>   To authorize this computer you must first deauthorize 
>   one of the other computers.

As far as I know, my only option is to deauthorize all computers and then re-authorize the ones I'm using one by one. I would rather be able to choose one or two that I want to deauthorize, freeing up authorization "slots" for my new computer.

Is it possible to deauthorize some but not all computers for iTunes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you have to do it from each computer that you want to deauthorize.

Go in the menu to Store > Deauthorize This Computer.

If however you don't have access to the computers you want to deauthorize, your only option is to deauthorize all computers, and then reauthorize the ones you want authorize. iTunes will not give you a list of authorized computers to select from to deauthorize. If you visit Store > View My Account, you can see how many are authorized, but you cannot see which ones are authorized.

Note: Apple allows for the mass deautherization only ONCE per year.

Comment: Should note that Apple allows the mass deautherization of all five computers once per year.

Comment: Wow, I did not now that. Thanks for the tip